# jquery datepicker min max not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Jquery UI datepicker breaking when adding min max dates. Heres my code, works fine with the dateformat and allowTimes, but brings up a blank calender when adding min / max dates.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format:'d/m/Y H:i',
        minDate: new Date(2014, 10, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2014, 11, 31),
        allowTimes:[
          '11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00',
          '18:00','18:30','19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30','21:00','21:30'
        ]
      });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: That's not the jQueryUI datepicker. What plugin are you using?

Comment: Are you talking about the DateTimePicker Plugin? There's an example for min: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#minDate and max: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#maxTime.

Comment: using this datepicker http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [this datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), try specifying the min and max dates as string:

```
// assuming default value for
// formatDate which is Y/m/d
minDate: '2014/11/01'
maxDate: '2014/12/31'
```

Comment: my bad i was using a very similar plugin - http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ which uses slightly different options

Comment: minDate: '2014/11/01',
maxDate: '2014/12/31',